# How to show a responsive image in Firefox with flexbox

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox

I can't figure it out, how to create an vertical aligned image in Firefox with flexbox.

My Code works in Safari

but not in Firefox:

[Firefox Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtsbT.png)

The image overlaps keeps overlapping the parent div when schrinking the window.

Here is my css:

```
    .wrapper {
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      bottom: 10px;
      left: 10px;
      right: 10px;
      border: 1px solid red;
      padding: 10px;
      }

      .flexbox {
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      border: 1px solid green;
      }

      .flex-child {
      border: 2px solid blue;
      }

      .flex-child img {
      max-width: 100%;
      max-height:100%;
      height: auto;
      }
```

And here the html:

```
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="flexbox">
        <div class="flex-child">
          <img src="http://dummyimage.com/800X600/000/fff">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And the link to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/luxio/wL15mb0w/).

Comment: Actually your code *"works"* in Chrome and Firefox but not in Safari ;)

Comment: What about: https://jsfiddle.net/wL15mb0w/8/

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks, but I want to have the image vertical aligned in the the wraper div : [Screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7120961/screenshots/safari.jpg)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: Why does it not work in Safari: Here are two screenshots from Safari different sizes. This is want I it too look like in Firefox: [example 1](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7120961/screenshots/safari2.png) [example 2](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7120961/screenshots/safari3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this not the best solution, but a least it works in Chrome, Safari and Firefox:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  background: url("http://dummyimage.com/800X600/000/fff") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/luxio/wL15mb0w/10/)